# How to post nested array object with kotlin using retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm trying to use post method in retrofit but confused how to implement it

How can I implement a retrofit using the post method?

```
{
    "companyId": "id8921",
    "employee": [
        {
            "id": "em128",
            "age": 38
        },
        {
            "id": "emp292",
            "age": 44
        },
        {
            "id": "emp321",
            "age": 33
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use RequestBody data class :

```
data class RequestBody(
    val companyId: String,
    val employee: List<Employee>
)

data class Employee(
    val age: Int,
    val id: String
)
```

Answer (score 2):

This how to post array object as form-url_encoded just use this in retrofit

```
@POST("api_url")
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<MasterResponse<JobCardSaveResponse>> jobCardSave(@FieldMap Map<String, Object> _jobCardRequest,
                                                      @Field("qty[]") List<String> qty,
                                                      @Field("service_id[]") List<String> service_id);
```